# I would like to compute the integral

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, polar-coordinates, line-integrals

$\int_0^{2\pi}-e^{\cos(t)}[\sin(t)\cdot \cos(\sin(t))+\cos(t)\cdot \sin(\sin(t)]\,dt$

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics SE. It is considered good practise on this website to show what you have tried in the question so far and where you got stuck, instead of asking the direct solution for your problem. You can edit in the additions needed to your post by clicking on the 'edit' button below the tags of the question... :-)

Comment: Using Magic Box,  answer is: $0$.

Answer (score 3):

Notice that the integral takes the form of $$\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{d}{dx} [f(x)\cdot g(x)] \; dx$$ where $f(x)=e^{\cos{(t)}}$ and $g(x)=\cos{\left(\sin{t}\right)}$.

$$\int_0^{2\pi}-e^{\cos(t)}[\sin(t)\cdot \cos(\sin(t))+\cos(t)\cdot \sin(\sin(t)]\;dt=e^{\cos{(t)}}\cdot \cos{\left(\sin{t}\right)} \big \rvert_0^{2\pi}=\boxed{0}$$